# Avoid unnecessary join in many-to-many relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have two tables in my database, called `media_blog` and `media_category`. There is a third table called `media_blog_category`, which relates blogs to the categories they belong to (a blog can belong to many categories, and a category may contain many blogs). This relationship is mapped in Hibernate/JPA as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="media_blog")
public class Blog {
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=MediaCategory.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "media_blog_category", 
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "blog_id")}, 
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "media_category_id")}
    )
    private Set<MediaCategory> categories;

    // Here goes the setters and getters for fields name and categories
}

@Entity
@Table(name="media_category")
public class MediaCategory {
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="categories")
    private List<Blog> blogs;

    // Here goes the setters and getters for fields name and blogs
}
```

When I retrieve a blog from the database, using `Blog b = Blog.find(id)` the following single query is logged into debug console:

```
select blog0_.id as id11_0_, blog0_.name as name11_0_ 
from media_blog blog0_ where blog0_.id=?
```

The lazy fetch type set on field `categories` works as expected, since no category information was queried.

But the following query is performed when doing `Set<MediaCategory> blogCategories = b.getCategories()`:

```
select categories0_.blog_id as blog1_11_1_, 
    categories0_.media_category_id as media2_1_, 
    mediacateg1_.id as id2_0_,
    mediacateg1_.name as name2_0_ 
from media_blog_category categories0_ 
inner join media_category mediacateg1_ 
   on categories0_.media_category_id=mediacateg1_.id 
where categories0_.blog_id=?
```

The problem is that I'm interested in the category IDs only (field `media_category_id` in table `media_blog_category`), but I noticed the query does a join with the `media_category` table and retrieves all fields of each category (in this case, the field `name`, but there will be more in the future) in order to populate the MediaCategory objects. There is a performance penalty, since it is doing joins to get information I'm not going to use.

Is there a way to avoid Hibernate to do this join, so it populates the variable `blogCategories` above with MediaCategory proxies (where only the `id` field is available - that's all I need), and delay the retrieval of the rest of category fields to the moment when I invoke the "getName()" (or another column getter) of a MediaCategory proxy object?

What I'm trying to do is similar to what is done in this post:
http://256stuff.com/gray/docs/misc/hibernate_lazy_field_access_annotations.shtml

But for many-to-many relationships.
I've tried the approach shown in that post, so annotated the `id` field in class `MediaCategory` with `@AccessType("property")`, but it didn't work. It seems it is not suited for many to many relationships, but for one-to-one relationships only.

Thanks!